# How to (efficiently) check if any two elements differ by 10

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following column in a -- pandas -- dataframe:

```
      x   
1   589 
2   354 
3   692 
4   474 
5   739 
6   731 
7   259 
8   723 
9   497 
10   48
```

Note: I've changed the indexing to start at 1 (see test data).

I simply wish to test if the difference between any two of the items in this column are less than 10. 
Final result: **No two elements** should have an absolute difference less than 10.

Goal:

```
      x   
1   589 
2   354 
3   692 
4   474 
5   749    #
6   731 
7   259 
8   713    #
9   497 
10   48
```

Perhaps this could be done using:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

However, that has not be successful thus far...

Given I'm looking to perform element-wise comparisions, I don't expect staging speed...

---

Test Data:

```
import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1,stim_numb+1), columns= ['x'])
 df['x'] = [589, 354, 692, 474, 739, 731, 259, 723, 497, 48]
```

Comment: You could put them into buckets of 10 and then compare any items that are in the same or in adjacent buckets. Also, what about 723 and 731? Or did you mean numbers that have the same tens-place?

Comment: @tobias_k  Thanks, for the suggestion -- and yes; that was human error on my part. Updating.

Comment: @DSM I apologize if my question was imprecise. No, I do not mean contiguous items.

Comment: So what output do you expect if the numbers are [0,0,0]? Or [0,1,2]?

Comment: Another way might be to sort the list, compare and shift successive elements, and then sort back.

Comment: Are they all integer?

Comment: @tobias_k ... that's actually a very elegant approach. Moreover, thankfully, order is irrelevant.

Comment: @tobias_k: yeah, but your point about introducing new < 10 differences by our addition is a good one.  We need to know whether we're doing the addition for its own sake, or whether we're trying to find a state where all items are separated by >= 10.

Comment: @Jianxun Li Yes, they're all integers

Comment: @DSM I updated the question. I misspoke. I'm trying to find a state where all items are separated by >= 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution might be to sort the list, then compare consecutive items, adding `10` whenever the difference is too small, and then sorting the list back to the original order (if necessary).

```
from operator import itemgetter
lst = [589, 354, 692, 474, 739, 731, 259, 723, 497, 48]
# temp is list as pairs of original index and value, sorted by value
temp = [[i, e] for i, e in sorted(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1))]
last = None
for item in temp:
    while last is not None and item[1] < last + 10:
        item[1] += 10
    last = item[1]
# sort the list back to original order using the index from the tuple
lst_new = [e for i, e in sorted(temp, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Result is `[589, 354, 692, 474, 759, 741, 259, 723, 497, 48]`

This is using plain Python lists; maybe it can be done more elegantly in Pandas or Numpy.

Comment: I think this is very elegant, personally. Thank you very much.

Comment: I take it the assumption here is that all elements are positive? consider the input [-13, 8, 19]. Also not entirely sure why but this code doesn't work with Python 3, http://ideone.com/THda31.

Comment: @shuttle87 Agreed, `0` was not a good initial value for `last`. About Python 3: `map` will return an iterator that is exhausted after the first loop. Edited.

Comment: @shuttle87 in my problem at least, all values are integers  > 0.